# Zxing Reading Algorithm Black Boxes

Tags: barcode, zxing, zxing.net

I am using zxing algorithm to read barcode with C#. I noticed that Zxing is not reading when the barcode is black around, how can I fix this problem? My image and code is given under this post.

```
       ZXing.BarcodeReader reader = new ZXing.BarcodeReader
        {
            AutoRotate = true,
            TryInverted = true,
            Options = new ZXing.Common.DecodingOptions
            {
                TryHarder = true,
                PureBarcode = false,
                PossibleFormats = Formats,                   
            }
        };
```

[image]

Comment: Do you use the newest version of ZXing.Net? I tried your image with the WinFormsDemo application of the current version of ZXing.Net and it decoded the barcode without any problems.

Comment: https://github.com/zxing-cpp/zxing-cpp I am using this library for c++ with opencv, in C# it is work bu in c++ it is not working.

Comment: I only know the C# version. I can't help with c++ problems.